# Comparing the sums of the elements on both sides of an element 'N' in an array(attempt 2)

Tags: c++, arrays

I took into consideration the hints I received, I applied some modular thinking and then tried again. The program runs. Depending on the set of values I hard-wire into the elements of the array, I receive as output, the index where the sum of the elements on the left is equal to the sum of the elements on the right. I understand this to have been the objective of the exercise.

I chose not to use a vector in this exercise because I need the practice for remembering that an array has a constant pointer to position 1 and as such, when an array is passed to a function, one must remember to also pass along the size of the array, or,alternately inside the function where the array is being passed, one can loop through the array and count the number of elements therein, thereafter using count as the array size.

Please criticize my new and functional code and point out anything else that I have done wrong.
Thank you.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/***************************************
* RIGHT SIDE OF ARRAY
* Calculates sum of elements right of n
***************************************/
int rightSideOfArray(int arrayOne[], int size, int i)
{
    int n = 0;

    //loop through array and get right hand sum
    for (int j = 1 + i; j < size; j++)
    {

        n += arrayOne[j];

    }
    return n;


}


/***************************************
* LEFT SIDE OF ARRAY
* Calculates sum of elements left of n
***************************************/
int leftSideOfArray(int arrayOne[], int size, int i)
{
    int n2 = 0;

    //find left hand sum
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        n2 += arrayOne[j];

    }
    return n2;

}



int main()
{
    //define and declare array
    int const SIZE = 7;
    int arrayOne[SIZE] =
    { 1,2,3,4,3,2,1 };
    int n = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
    int count = 0;

    //do comparison
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {

    //compare right hand and left hand side and return right values
    if (rightSideOfArray(arrayOne, SIZE, i) == 
    leftSideOfArray(arrayOne,       SIZE, i))

     counter++;
    cout << i << endl;

}
    if (counter == 0)

    cout << -1 << endl;

system("PAUSE");

return 0;

}
```

---

Old Code: First attempt
I read a previous solution to this same query but I can't figure out where I went wrong. The challenge as I understand it is to loop through an integer array, at each, element 'i', I must add all the elements to the left of 'i' to get the 'left side sum'. Then I must add all the elements to the right of 'i' to get the 'right hand sum'. There after, I should compare the sums for the right hand and left hand sides of my array. 
If both sums are equal, I should have my function return the index at which the equalization of right hand and left hand side occurred. Else, I should return -1.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting only '-1' as my answer?

```
int equalSidesOfAnArray(int arrayOne[], int n, int n2)
{

    //loop through array and get right hand sum
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arrayOne); i++)
    {

        for (int j = 1 + i; j < sizeof(arrayOne); j++)
        {
            n += arrayOne[j];
            n2 += arrayOne[j - 1];
        }

        if (n == n2)
            return arrayOne[i];
        else
            return -1;

    }

}

int main()
{
    // define and declare array
    int const SIZE = 7;
    int arrayOne[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    int n = 0;
    int n2 = 0;


    int answer = equalSidesOfAnArray(arrayOne, n, n2);
    cout << answer << endl;


    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `sizeof(arrayOne)` is the size of a pointer.  Not likely OP's design goal.

Comment: `cout << answer << endl;` is not valid C

Comment: I am using C++, even so,

Comment: Can you help more?

Comment: your logic is wrong.

Comment: Ok, all of it or any particular part? Can you point me in more specific direction?

Comment: 0) You need to pass the length of the array. 1) Calculation of `n` and `n2` are incorrect. 3) It is necessary to initialize `n` and `n2` each time the inner loop ends. 4) It can not `return -1;` until the outer loop ends.

Comment: 5) `return arrayOne[i];` : You should _return the index_.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `arrayOne` as parameter of the function is a pointer to the first element of the array, and `sizeof(arrayOne)` is the size of this pointer, not the size `SIZE` of your array.
And even within main(), `sizeof(arrayOne)` would return `SIZE * sizeof(int)`.

As you are coding in C++, use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)/[std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and banish C arrays. This you save you such trouble and [much more](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#arrays-are-evil).

And think about where you are initializing `n` and `n2` (which you don't need to pass as parameter), and returning `-1`.